# C# Use 'this' Keyword in a class

Tags: c#, winforms

i have a code for creating a LineShape from two points .

```
class MyMenu
{
    public static void AddLine()
    {

        ShapeContainer canvas = new ShapeContainer();
        LineShape theLine = new LineShape();

        canvas.Parent = this;

        theLine.Parent = canvas;
        theLine.BorderColor = SystemColors.ControlDarkDark;

        theLine.StartPoint = new System.Drawing.Point(-3, 154);
        theLine.EndPoint = new System.Drawing.Point(212, 154);

    }
}
```

. i want to create a class and use from there but i end up having an error .

```
Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static method, or static field initializer
```

i tried to fix it like this but nothing !

```
 Form1 MyForm = new Form1();
        canvas.Parent = MyForm;
```

Thanks you !

Comment: check this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx

Comment: What does "but nothing" mean? In any case, `this` has no meaning in a *static* method - this points to the current object instance and static methods have no current instance. That's basic C#.

Comment: Keyword `static` implies you do not have an instance of an object. While `this` is referring to the current instance. Remove `static` from method declaration.

Comment: You did not ask a question.  This is a question and answer site; what is your **precise** question?

Comment: In a static method there is no 'this', as the error indicates. What is not clear about this? Do you understand what 'static' and 'this' mean?

Comment: `this` keyword refers to the current `object`. In case of static methods, you dont need a object to call it, so there is no object.

Comment: *Why* do you want to assign anything to `parent`? What value should be assigned to this property? Why not leave it empty? If you need to assign your current form to it, just pass an instance to your form as a parameter to AddLine

Comment: It's not really clear why this method is `static` in the first place.  "Adding a line" sounds like an action that would be performed on an instance of something.

Comment: I wish to note that numerous comments have suggested making the method non static.  However, `MyMenu` is not a `Form`, so removing `static` from `AddLine`'s signature won't actually help.  If you wish to make `AddLine` non-static, it would need to be an instance method on your `Form` class, rather than a static method on the `MyMenu` class.  Usually that's the approach you'd want to take, as `Form` instances tend to have a bunch of protected members (especially stuff from the designer) that you'll want to interact with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, you can try passing the form reference into the method(if that is what you mean).

```
class MyMenu
{
    public static void AddLine(Form f)
    {

        ShapeContainer canvas = new ShapeContainer();
        LineShape theLine = new LineShape();

        canvas.Parent = f;

        theLine.Parent = canvas;
        theLine.BorderColor = SystemColors.ControlDarkDark;

        theLine.StartPoint = new System.Drawing.Point(-3, 154);
        theLine.EndPoint = new System.Drawing.Point(212, 154);

    }
}
```

And from the Form:

```
MyMenu.AddLine(this);
```